# mysql query with joins, order by and limits

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query in mysql which contains JOIN, ORDER BY and LIMIT,
The Query is

> SELECT r.* FROM register r INNER JOIN payments p ON r.matri_id =
>   p.pmatri_id WHERE p.p_plan LIKE '%Free%' ORDER BY r.index_id DESC
>   LIMIT 0, 10

where register table contains almost 5098 Records and payments table contains almost 5023 records, Now the thing happening is when I am running this Query it's taking ages to take the result
Its taking almost 102 seconds to 147 seconds (If I am putting the limit on 10 too).
And When I am trying to run

> select * from payments
>   or
>   select * from register

query from register or payments, the whole table results comes within 0.01 seconds.

I had also tried modifying the above query, everything is working fine if I am removing the **ORDER BY**, After Removing the order by with joins, its taking only 0.04 seconds or less..

I don't know where I am missing or where I have left something, Please review the query and tell me the solution.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Manish if you have another question, then better not change an old question. But post a new one.  And this one is closed even.

Comment: But I am not able to post new question :(

Comment: Ouch. I never experience such ban. But it seems [SO is rather strict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) to protect itself from bad questions. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a re-write, using left joins.

```sql
SELECT r.*, 
m.mtongue_id, m.mtongue_name, 
rel.religion_id, rel.religion_name, 
c.caste_id, c.caste_name, 
con.country_id, con.country_name,
st.state_id, st.state_name, 
ct.city_id, ct.city_name, 
des.desg_id, des.desg_name, 
ocp.ocp_id, ocp.ocp_name 
FROM register r
LEFT JOIN mothertongue m ON r.m_tongue = m.mtongue_id
LEFT JOIN religion rel ON r.religion = rel.religion_id
LEFT JOIN caste c ON r.caste = c.caste_id
LEFT JOIN country con ON r.country_id = con.country_id
LEFT JOIN state st ON r.state_id = st.state_id 
LEFT JOIN city ct ON r.city = ct.city_id
LEFT JOIN designation des ON r.designation = des.desg_id
LEFT JOIN occupation ocp ON r.occupation = ocp.ocp_id
WHERE r.matri_id = 'MF1202'
```

Assuming that the joined id fields are all the primary key in their table.

Comment: Thank you so much LukStorms!! It's working great, previously my query was getting out of memory, but now I am able to run this query....

Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!